# openMP threads and iterations

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

So i have this part of code.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (it = 0; it < itime; it++){
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
   do something1..
   for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
   do something2..
   }
  }
  do something3..
 }
```

The for loop with the `it` counter iterates 20 times(0-19).
The value of `N` does not matter at the time.
What happens is that the iterations are "spread" on 4 threads.

```
thread #0 gets [0,1,2,3,4]
thread #1 gets [5,6,7,8,9]
thread #2 gets [10,11,12,13,14]
thread #3 gets [15,16,17,18,19]
```

All i want to do is to spread the iterations in my own order like:
`thread #0 [0,4,8,10,16]` etc...

Is there any way i can achieve this using the openmp?

Comment: Define "int numbers[] = {0,4,8,10,16 ...};" before the for loop and then access that in the thread using "numbers[it]". Just a suggestion.

Comment: so you suggest using 4 arrays (with the counters) and 4 for loops so i can access 1 loop with each thread?

Comment: As I understand, you don't need 4 for loops for 4 threads. What's inside the main for loop will be divided to 4 threads. So 1 array (with length 20) is enough.

Comment: I will try using the schedule clause.

Comment: For this specific case, you can just use `schedule(static,1)` which  will distribute the iterations by batches of 1 in a round-robin fashion among the threads. BTW, Don't forget to declare `i` and `j` `private`

Comment: Assuming that "10" was mean to b e "12" (I.e. thread zero gets {0,4,8,12,16}, then @Giles is right, schedule(static,1) will do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution.

```
int numbers[] = { 0,4,8,10,16,1,2,3,5,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19 };//define as u wish
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (int it = 0; it < 20; it++) {
        //cout <<"Thread "<< omp_get_thread_num() << " gets :" << numbers[it] << endl;
        int num = numbers[it];//use this instead of "it"
}
```

This might not be the best solution.

Comment: I dont need to print the "thread" section mentioned above. I just need the main for loop(it counter) to iterate through certain values of the it variable on each thread.

Comment: So don't print it. I commented that line. Now look.